# C++ set slower than Java TreeSet?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, set

I was working on leetcode problem [792. Number of Matching Subsequences](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-matching-subsequences/), and one of the initial solutions I came up with was to create a list of ordered sets. Then we can determine if a word is a subsequence of string `s` by trying to find the ceiling of the next available character of string `word` using the current index we are in of `s`. If we can reach the end of `word`, it is then a subsequence, otherwise, it is not.

I know this is not the optimal solution, but what I found surprising was the solution was able to pass in Java, but not with C++(which is significantly slower). I'm still relatively new to C++ and in the process of learning it, so I'm not sure if there is some copying going on, or some other reason why my C++ solution would be much slower?

I have tried to change the way I was passing variables, and even tried to remove the `isSub()` function completely and write the logic in `numMatchingSubseq()`, however, it was still significantly slower than the Java implementation. Would anyone know why this is?

**Java Solution**

```java
class Solution {
    public int isSub(List<TreeSet<Integer>> alpha, String word) {
        int N = word.length();
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        
        while (i < N) {
            TreeSet<Integer> st = alpha.get(word.charAt(i++) - 'a');
            Integer e = st.ceiling(j);
            if (e == null) return 0;
            j = e + 1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    public int numMatchingSubseq(String s, String[] words) {
        List<TreeSet<Integer>> alpha = new ArrayList<TreeSet<Integer>>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
            alpha.add(new TreeSet<Integer>());
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
            alpha.get(s.charAt(i) - 'a').add(i);
        
        int ans = 0;
        for (String word : words) 
            ans += isSub(alpha, word);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

**C++ Solution**

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int isSub(vector<set<int>>& alpha, const string& word) {
        int i = 0, j = 0, N = word.size();
        while (i < N) {
            set<int> st = alpha[word[i++] - 'a'];
            auto it = st.lower_bound(j);
            if (it == st.end()) return false;
            j = *it + 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int numMatchingSubseq(string s, vector<string>& words) {
        vector<set<int>> alpha(26);
        int M = s.size(), ans = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
            alpha[s[i] - 'a'].insert(i);
        for (const auto& word: words) 
            ans += isSub(alpha, word);
        
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Anyway Leetcode is not the place to learn C++ nor is it a good environment for getting reliable performance statistics. I think a lot of time is lost by using C++ inefficiently or incorrectly (like creating set<int> over and over again in an inner loop). Really don't look at other C++ solutions on leetcode, their quality is really poor (from a C++ point of view), learn C++ somewhere else. (Note object lifetime and philosophies differ quite a lot between Java and C++, you would do well to learn the differences)

Comment: How do you compile the c++ program? How do you measure the time? You pass `string s` per value, instead of by reference, depending on the size of it, it can make a huge difference.

Comment: `alpha[s[i] - 'a']` -- FYI, this will not work on systems that are not ASCII (such as EBCDIC), where the alpha characters are not contiguous in the collating sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely some copying happening in the C++ version that isn't happening in the Java version. For instance `st` could be a reference

```
set<int>& st = alpha[word[i++] - 'a'];
```

Comment: `find`? on a vector?

Comment: @numzero Oops, I was thinking it was a set.

Comment: @john Yes, that was it! I totally blanked on the temp `st` I used was being created as a copy. It's still slower than the Java implementation, but as it now passes, that could be possibly chalked up to the variable and not-so-precise performance statistics of leetcode.

Comment: @AdamC - Java code *can* be faster than C++ if you have short runtimes, so the garbage collector never kicks in. It will be like C++ with lots of `new` but no `delete`. Saves time (and wastes everything else).